# Leafletjs override doubletap

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

How can I override a double tap onto a LeafletJS map?
I do not want to zoom into the map, I want a custom procedure to start instead.
It's a angular-leaflet-directive within ionic.

Edit:

I was pointed to the `doubleClickZoom` property (I must have been blind :) ). However, when I set `doubleClickZoom = false` , the two finger zoom is disabled as well... ? I want to keep two finger zoom, but disable doubleClickZoom. As an alternative, I could go with `trippleClickZoom`, which is obviously not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Please consult the documentation and the appropriately-named option [doubleClickZoom](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-doubleclickzoom).

Comment: Thanks, I must have overlooked that.